# Java Code that works well on Windows does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I've got some Java (SpringBoot app) code that i copied 1:1 on two machines: one with Windows, second with Ubuntu operating system.

The code consists of:
A `DTO` like:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Simple {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "12.00")
    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1)
    @Max(value = 1)
    private final BigDecimal test;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/test/")
@AllArgsConstructor
class SimulatorController {

    @PostMapping(value = "test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    void test(
            @Valid
            @NotNull
            @RequestBody Simple simple
    ) {
        log.info("Got  request [{}]", simple);
    }
```

Main pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pl.bnp.retail.okd.ho</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend-spring-template-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>app</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>app</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>a</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend-spring-template-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>a.AppConfig</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

`App` pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>pl.bnp.retail.okd.ho</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend-spring-template-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And now it's weird cause on `Ubuntu` I get in swagger an error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `pl.bnp.retail.okd.ho.simulator.model.SimpleSimulatorInputWithInstallmentMonthlyAmount`
>   (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from
>   Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 3]

But on `Windows` it works fine (it prints nicely `ToString()` content)

I wonder why?

I even deleted all repositories from `.m2` catalogue on `Windows` then build the project again but still it worked fine.

The only difference i can i see is that on Windows i have Java 11.0.2, but on Ubuntu it is Java 11.0.4.

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Edit:**
Adding additional file `lombok.config` on `Ubuntu` with

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

Eventually adding also `@AllArgsConstructor` now it's hard to break it on Ubuntu even if this annotation is gone.

Makes code run fine but i wonder why? Why is there difference beetwen operating systems in this scenario?

Comment: As is I don't think we can help much.  If you post the entire stack trace we might be able to point you in the right direction, but even then it's likely that the problem is in the library you are using.  It MIGHT involve loading a serialized object, but there really isn't enough info there.

Comment: @BillK I found that adding `lombok.config` with `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true` makes the code run fine on `Ubuntu`. The question is why there is a difference beetwen operating systems here? Eventually adding also `@AllArgsConstructor` now it's hard to break it on `Ubuntu` even if this annotation is gone.

Comment: You're handling strings which means encoding and line separators need to be considered. Also your error is with Swagger and Lombok and as third party libraries, you don't know if they have dependencies on a particular host operating system.

Comment: @Abra FYI: `GIT` has flag `core.autocrlf` it handles well `line separators` it's not a problem. `Encoding` is another topic, one solution is to use `messageSource.setDefaultEncoding()` method which in independent regardless of operating system. I am not sure what do you mean by saying that's `my error`. In my opinion `Swagger` is like standard nowadays and `Lombok` is widely used.